# Use object keys given by JSON_SEARCH to find a different key in the same object in mysql/mariadb

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I have some records of payments in the database and I keep the items belonging to the payment as a JSON(LONGTEXT) column in mariadb. For example the items columns would be like below.

| items |
| --- |
| [{"id":"a4","quantity":1,"title":"A4 Sheets","unitprice":7000,"total":7000},{"id":"reports","quantity":1,"title":"Reports","unitprice":750,"total":750},{"id":"other","quantity":2,"title":"Cap","unitprice":250,"total":500}] |
| [{"id":"exam3_5","quantity":1,"title":"Exam Fees : Grade 03 - 05","unitprice":750,"total":750},{"id":"a4","quantity":1,"title":"A4 Sheets","unitprice":7000,"total":7000},{"id":"reports","quantity":1,"title":"Reports","unitprice":750,"total":750}] |
| [{"id":"other","quantity":10,"title":"Test1","unitprice":1,"total":10},{"id":"other","quantity":10,"title":"Test2","unitprice":2,"total":20}] |

what I want to do is find objects that have the id of "other" and get the total of each object.

I can get objects with other by `JSON_SEARCH(items, 'all', 'other')`
and it will give results like below, just an example. Not according to the first table.

| JSON_SEARCH(items, 'all', 'other') |
| --- |
| "$[2].id" |
| ["$[0].id", "$[1].id"] |

So i know which indexes of the array have i need to look at. Now i need to get the total of every object which has id as "other".

I can do a `JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].total')` which gives me

| JSON_SEARCH(items, 'all', 'other') | JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].total') |
| --- | --- |
| "$[2].id" | [7000, 750, 500] |
| ["$[0].id", "$[1].id"] | [10, 20] |

I need a third column something like this

| JSON_SEARCH(items, 'all', 'other') | JSON_EXTRACT(items, '$[*].total') | Required Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "$[2].id" | [7000, 750, 500] | 500 |
| ["$[0].id", "$[1].id"] | [10, 20] | 30 |

Finally I want a cumulative total of the "Required Column" which I guess I can do by SUM(Required Column).

Any advice on achieving the "Required Column"?
I'm using nodejs as the backend. I could do the processing there but I want to know if it can be done with mysql itself.
Thanks

Comment: What version of MariaDB Server are you using? If you are using MariaDB Server >= 10.6.0, one option would be to use [JSON_TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/), see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=4a659dff35b298115792a005ccba5e92).

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer with the fiddle. Unfortunately I'm using 10.4.21 that's why JSON_TABLE is not working as you have mentioned. But thanks to your fiddle I learned the ROLLUP keyword which helped me alot later.